# TeamCity reports incorrect code coverage with dotCover for c# unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, teamcity, code-coverage, dotcover

I am somewhat new to TeamCity. I have set it up for a Visual Studio solution.

I am using NUnit step to run unit tests and dotCover for code coverage. Problem is, there are particular parts of my code that I know are covered by unit tests but in the code coverage report, it shows them with zero coverage.

I know the DLLs are created just fine because I run a dir /s command and can see all the test DLLs.

- The NUnit step uses MSIL 4.0 platform and the test path looks like this:

  `**/bin/Debug/*Tests.dll`
- There are no filters under code coverage.

Many tests are run. But there are some specific tests that are not present in the search report when I search.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me. The DLL that was being ignored was spelled `*Test.dll` instead of `*Tests.dll`. I use `*Tests.dll` in my test path.

The issue got fixed once I changed it to `*Test*.dll`

Answer (score 1):

Can you please provide information about your NUnit step, especially about .Net Coverage (Filters).

Can you also confirm that tests are actually run?

Full build log (pasted in pastebin.com or such provider) would be also appreciated.

Comment: Nevermind, it was not being run because my test path was incorrect.